# How do I construct a pure function to extract data fields from records that are strings?

Tags: programming, function-construction, string-manipulation

How can I get from `datasegment` format to the `finalsegment` format with a pure function? The data fields are fixed length. There are no separators between the fields.

a) list

```
wordlength = {11, 20, 10, 9};
from = 2; to = 3;  

datasegment = {"        109Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  6519218  ",
               "       2082Mint Cream          39:24:41  7314284  ",
               "       6790Indian Red          21:57:53  3368766  "};

finalsegment = {"Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  ",
                "Mint Cream          39:24:41  ",
                "Indian Red          21:57:53  "};
```

b) string

```
dataline = {"       1556Floral White        29:48:49  7856900  "};

finalline = {"Floral White        29:48:49  "};
```

---

### **Update**

Final solutions were found for the task. I would like to share it here:

```
inlist = RandomChoice[
{"       2524Lemon Chiffon       22:51:28  1881779  ",
 "       3085Teal                19:22:24  9744812  ",
 "       5935Light Yellow        03:32:54  8374029  ",
 "       6128Powder Blue         27:20:07  7315046  "}, 
400000];  

wordLength = {11, 20, 10, 9};
fromWord = 2;
numberOfWords = 2;  

fields = Length[wordLength];
borders = {{1, wordLength[[1]]}};
Do[
borders = 
FlattenAt[{borders, {borders[[i, 2]] + 1, 
borders[[i, 2]] + wordLength[[i + 1]]}}, 1], {i, fields - 1}];
grenz = {borders[[fromWord, 1]], 
borders[[fromWord + numberOfWords - 1, 2]] };
outlist = StringTake[inlist, grenz];// Timing  

{0.141, Null}
```

The honor goes to the very concerned in this task. Every detail of their conception was vital to the solution. Keep'n rocking.

Comment: Are you certain you want to keep your data as strings? You may find it more convenient to structure `dateline` as a list, as in `{{109, "Lemon Chiffon"}, {25, 22, 29}, 6519218}`. Even if I were only interested in displaying the data, I would use a list rather than a string.

Comment: I am certain about it.

Answer (score 8):

With a fixed length you can use `StringTake` and set the region you like

```
StringTake[#, {12, 11 + 20 + 10}] & /@ 
{"        109Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  6519218  ", 
 "       2082Mint Cream          39:24:41  7314284  ", 
 "       6790Indian Red          21:57:53  3368766  "}

(*
Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  
Mint Cream          39:24:41  
Indian Red          21:57:53  
*)
```

### Update

You noted, that the creation of the appropriate region for `StringTake` is maybe tedious. For this, you can write a function which takes your word boundaries and the columns you want to extract and returns another function, an *extractor* which can take one string and extracts the appropriate columns. This has the advantage that you have to give the word boundaries and the columns only one time and can use the extractor as often as you like.

Taking your `{11, 20, 10, 9}` boundaries as example, the integral part of the function is a combination of `Accumulate`, `Partition` and a `Map` which adds 1 to the start position of each word region.

```
({#1+1,#2}&@@@Partition[Accumulate@{11,20,10,9},2,1])
(* {{12,31},{32,41},{42,50}} *)
```

As you see you get exactly the positions you need for `StringTake`, e.g. first word goes from 12 to 31, etc. Surely, you don't want *all* words from a string, because then you wouldn't need a *selector*, but wouldn't it be nice, if you could use the same syntax as you can use for `Part`, namely specify single elements `{1,2,3,5}` or ranges `{1;;3, 5}`? This is done in the second part of our selector, where we use a `string` which needs to be filled:

```
dataSelector[columns_, wordlengths_] := 
 With[{wordregions = ({#1 + 1, #2} & @@@
    Partition[Accumulate@Prepend[wordlengths, 0], 2, 1])},
  Function[string, StringJoin[StringTake[string, #] & /@ 
    (Part[wordregions, #] & /@ columns)]]]
```

The usage is now simple: with `in` being your sample data you can do

```
in={"        109Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  6519218  ",
    "       2082Mint Cream          39:24:41  7314284  ",
    "       6790Indian Red          21:57:53  3368766  "};

dataSelector[{4,2;;3,1},{11,20,10,9}]/@in
(*
{6519218  Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29          109,
 7314284  Mint Cream          39:24:41         2082,
 3368766  Indian Red          21:57:53         6790}
*)
```

### Update regarding comment

Yes, you are right, the first word could not be extracted but since it always ranges from 1 simply prepending 0 before calling `Accumulate` in the `dataSelector` function fixes the problem. Additionally, when you use the `dataSelector` to extract the say second and third word it returns a *list of strings*. When I look now at your sample, you maybe prefer to have *one* string back where all selected words are concatenated. I added the appropriate `StringJoin` to the function.

Depending on your level as *Mathematica* programmer, my `dataSelector` is a bad example since it's probably a bit harder to understand. When you want to create the output as in your last example with it, you have to use it like:

```
dataline = {"       1556Floral White        29:48:49  7856900  "};
sel = dataSelector[{2, 3}, {11, 20, 10, 9}];
sel[dataline]

(* "Floral White        29:48:49  " *)
```

or, if you want to extract the second and third word for a list of strings, you simply use `sel /@ in`. The important line to understand is the second. To create a selector function, you call for instance `dataSelector[{2, 3}, {11, 20, 10, 9}]` where `{2,3}` are the words you want to extract and the last parameter is the length of each word.

Important here is, that you can use the range specification `;;` and `All` like you can use it with `Part` (`[[]]`). Test for instance the output of the following examples

```
dataSelector[{All}, {11, 20, 10, 9}][dataline]
dataSelector[{1, 3 ;; 4}, {11, 20, 10, 9}][dataline]
dataSelector[{1, All, 2 ;; 4}, {11, 20, 10, 9}][dataline]
```

### Update 2

When your goal is speed, then you should call `StringTake[{s1,s2,...},{spec1,spec2,...}]`, this means you input all your datasets `{s1,s2,...}` in one call and you put all wordboundary specs in a list. This should be reasonable fast.

Your update contains the undefined variable `wb`. Would you mind to measure your method against the method below with the 4000000 elements in `data`?

```
data = RandomChoice[
   {"        109Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29  6519218  ",
    "       2082Mint Cream          39:24:41  7314284  ", 
    "       6790Indian Red          21:57:53  3368766  "}, 4000000];

dataSelector[columns_, wordlengths_] := 
  With[{wordregions = (Part[({#1 + 1, #2} & @@@             
          Partition[Accumulate@Prepend[wordlengths, 0], 2, 
           1]) , #] & /@ columns)},
    Function[string, StringJoin @@@ StringTake[string, wordregions]] ]

f = dataSelector[{2, 3}, {11, 20, 10, 9}];

AbsoluteTiming[f[data]] // First
```

Comment: You are right. Difficult part is to go from wordlength {11, 20, 10, 9} to your selection list {12, 11 + 20 + 10} and integrate that into your function. And be generic. You like to take an arbitrary start word and an arbitrary end word to build the resuld.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon I updated my answer.

Comment: OK.  .   .Dont you need the boundaries for the 1rst Word too?.   .   .And help me to use it.   .   .We need a result that looks the same as shown above in finalsegment.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon I changed the function and added additional explanation at the end. I hope you can use it now.

Comment: OK.   .   .A fast algorithmic solution was found.   .   .(see Update).  .  .Timing for 4.000.000 records.  .  .This function 23 sec, the algorithmic solution 1.3 sec

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon Can you measure the function in the very last update of my post?

Comment: Shure.  .   .   .Your are right.   .   .The variable named wb is of course the wordlenght of the original code above. Please modify it accordingly.   .   .The comparison reached the following results:.   .   .yours 4.9 sec. . . the other 1.3 sec

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is:

```
fun = Function[x, 
   x /. s_String :> 
     StringReplace[StringTrim@s, 
      NumberString ~~ Longest[y__] ~~ "  " ~~ NumberString ~~ 
        EndOfString :> (y ~~ "  ")]];
```

though I find strange that it does not work if I leave out the "  " ...

Comment: Can you give same elucidation where in your function to place  the variables wordlength, from, to and datasegment. How to call your function.

Comment: You can apply the function by   fun@datasegment  and  fun@dataline   and variable worldlength is just not needed.

Comment: OKWhat would you do if the number of "Words2 is 100. And you would like to take from 60 throgh 80?

Comment: OK.   .   .What would you do if the number of "Words" in datasegment is 100.  .(here we have 4).  .and you would like to take from 60 through 80?

Comment: I would read the documentation of ReadList and write a function to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said these strings were fixed position but here is a more generic approach:

```
Flatten@StringCases[datasegment, Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ z__ ~~ Whitespace
~~NumberString :> z]

(* {
"Lemon Chiffon       25:22:29 ", 
"Mint Cream          39:24:41 ", 
"Indian Red          21:57:53 "
} *)
```

This could be made more concise using Regular Expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately not generic. You like to take an arbitrary start word and an arbitrary end word to build the resuld.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon  hence I said "more generic" rather than "generic".